# Postgres query stalls when selecting explicit columns with an order by using a server side cursor with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a simple query that joins two (reasonably large) tables and iterates over the results with a server side cursor:

```
select * from tableA a join tableB b on (a.fid = b.id) order by a.id;
```

This query is fine and I can iterate over the results in chunks with a `fetchmany`.

However, as soon as I change the query to

```
select a.id from tableA a join tableB b on (a.fid = b.id) order by a.id
```

the `execute` call stalls and I'm unable to iterate over the results.

The `id` column on both tables is index via a `BTREE` index and the `fid` column is also indexed with a `BTREE` and is a constraint on `tableB.id`. `id` and `fid` are integers.

The reason I need to iterate over all the rows is because I'm creating a database export of sorts which cannot be accomplished via a `copy` command as it requires a join.

Comment: Any traceback of the problem? Anything you've learned from debugging the error logs?

Comment: Could you show us both query plans using EXPLAIN ANALYZE? Please post them at http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: table definitions would go a long way as well..., what is a.fid, and do you have key on it?

Comment: for  `select *` query : http://explain.depesz.com/s/Akr4

for  `select a.id` query: http://explain.depesz.com/s/yhir

Comment: @Ali-AkberSaifee: I don't see any timings, did you use EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN ANALYZE ?

Comment: explain, since explain analyze won't return in time for either query as each table is ~ 20M records.

Comment: can you post the tables definitions? so we can see keys and indexes?

Comment: Without further information, the only thing you could do is creating an index on a.id, increase work_mem and maybe change the setting for random_page_cost. This might speed up sorting. But, do you really need all data? If not, put a WHERE condition in your query.

Comment: Thanks @FrankHeikens. The indices are already there - my confusion is why switching out the `*` select for an explicit column select creates a problem

Comment: Have you recently run a vacuum analyze? I've had issues with postgresql not being smart enough to properly use indexes in certain cases where analyzing the tables with a vacuum fixes is.

Comment: Create a view from your joined tables, and `copy (select * from viewname) to...`.